# Laravel 4 Eloquent ORM accessing one-to-one relationship through dynamic properties

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to model a pretty straightforward relationship, between the 'Users' table and the 'User_profiles' table. Each user has a user_profile, so it's a simple one-to-one. As per the docs found @ http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#one-to-one I have added the following function to my User model:

```
public function user_profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('User_profile');
}
```

and this is the relationship defined in my User_profile model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

I am trying to access from the controller like this:

```
    // Get current user
    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    $profile = $user->user_profile;

    print_r($user);
    print_r($profile);

    echo "User's name is: " . $user->user_profile->first_name . ' ' . $user->user_profile->last_name;
```

Unfortunately printing $user prints out the User model fields just fine, but doesn't show any trace of a relationship; $profile is empty. The 'relations' array is also empty, which I'm guessing should maybe be filled.

I am trying to use the 'dynamic properties' as suggested here http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#dynamic-properties

Otherwise if I just go:

```
echo "User's name is: " . $user->user_profile()->first()->first_name . ' ' . $user->user_profile()->first()->last_name;
```

It works.. but I don't really like having to do that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

Ok so the problem had to do with using underscores in the class names. Laravel follows PSR 0 and 1 as outlined [here](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/tree/master/accepted).

What this means is I had to name my model class and filename UserProfile (even though my MySql table named remained 'user_profiles'), and then update my User model to have a function called userProfile().

Once I updated the naming, I could access the relationships automatically by doing something like:

```
$user = Auth::user();
echo $user->userProfile->first_name;
```

Comment: I love L4 but this aspect must catch a LOT of people out. I had a similar problem but in my case it was to do with product types and it turns out I had to name the relationship method `productType()` instead of `producttype()`. Thanks for posting and hopefully it helps out a few others.

Comment: Yes, plus it's annoying that the renaming happens for objects such as tables and their related tables, but you end up going back to the underscore naming for the table fields themselves, ie first_name. This inconsistency is mildly irritating.