# Laravel: Trying to get relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

**User:**

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    public function email_preferences()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('EmailPreference');
    }

}
```

**EmailPreference:**

```
class EmailPreference extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'email_preferences';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

}
```

**users** table

```
id PK
first_name
last_name
email
```

**email_preferences** table

```
id PK
user_id FK (users.id)
newsletter
```

I'm trying to display the email preferences for a user:

```
$user = Auth::user();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($user->email_preferences);
exit;
```

I get nothing...

Comment: Have you verified there is a related record in the db?

Comment: Yes, there is a record within `email_preferences`

Comment: Maybe also try adding `()` after your call in the print_r, even though it's supposed to be smart & work anyways.

Comment: Nah, that dumps the entire Eloquent model.

Comment: Umm... that's the idea. It gets you the related model.

Comment: In this instance it doesn't look like $user is an object. You're calling a static auth() function on it, and then trying to access a member function. try explicitly defining a user?

Comment: @PeterJewicz Auth::user() gets the currently authorized user. That's why that method exists... even so, if I ask for a specific User::find(1) ... same result

Comment: @mopo922 No, it dumps absolutely everything. It's a never ending amount of data. Not what anyone would want.

Comment: @dcolumbus `print_r($user->email_preferences());` would dump the Relation, which I believe has a recursive reference.  What do you get with `print_r($user->email_preferences()->count());` or `print_r($user->email_preferences()->lists('id'));`?

Comment: @patricus I get `Call to a member function email_preferences() on a non-object`

Comment: @dcolumbus You would only get that if $user is not an object. Are you logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
<?php
$user = Auth::user();
echo 'Receive newsletter? ' . ($user->emailPreferences->newsletter ? 'Yes' : 'No');
```

**EDIT:**

I did some digging & found that **underscores** can be tricky when used in Eloquent function/property names. If you eliminate the underscore, things should just work:

```
<?php
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public function emailPreferences()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('EmailPreference');
    }

}
```

See this answer: [Laravel 4 Eloquent ORM accessing one-to-one relationship through dynamic properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888029/laravel-4-eloquent-orm-accessing-one-to-one-relationship-through-dynamic-propert#answer-16888372)

Comment: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::$newsletter

Comment: How about: echo 'Receive newsletter? ' . ($user->email_preferences->newsletter ? 'Yes' : 'No');

Comment: @akrist That produces: `Trying to get property of non-object`